# Splitting string in JavaScript for further processing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to process a pasted string in JavaScript like this:

```
Introduction
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

Something Else
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.

Another Part: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.

Finish
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

This should get something like this:

```
<div><h1>Introduction</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p> 
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>

<div><h1>Something Else</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p></div>

<div><h1>Another Part</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>

<div><h1>Finish</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
```

---

**Explanation**

There are the Textblocks "Introduction", "Something else", "Another part" and "Finish" (these words are the "searching-string")
I need to find these blocks to wrap them with a div-element. The div-Element ends with the next textblock (or ending of the string)
One Problem for me is that the "searching strings" could end with a ":" a new line or with none of them... So the ":" or "Linebreak" in the heading should be removed.
It could be the case, that a block is missing. i.e. there is only "Introduction" and "Finish". So that would lead to two div-blocks.

```
var text;
var parts = text;
replace(/^[\n\s]*|[\n\s]*$/g, '');
split(/\n\s*\n/g);
```

But how do I get the headings? Like...

If "Introduction" -> Wrap Introduction with h1

And how do I get the p-tags?

Comment: controlling if the previous line is empty?

Comment: `Adobe Dreamweaver` does that I believe.

Comment: @RahulDesai It can be done with 5 lines of JS, no need to use a software...

Comment: @dystroy I am curious what are those 5 lines. :)

Comment: @RahulDesai I lied : it's not 5 lines but one line. Two if you want only short lines. Three if you count the one to get the div : `var div = document.getElementById('someId')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this :

```
html = text.trim().replace(/(.*?)(\n|:)(.*?)(\n\n|$)/mg, "<h1>$1</h1><p>$3</p>");
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/retux/2/edit)

---

I see you added the jQuery tag. So you may define a class for the elements you want to process and then do

```
$('.raw').html(function(_,h){
    return h.trim().replace(/(.*?)(\n|:)(.*?)(\n\n|$)/mg, "<h1>$1</h1><p>$3</p>")
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/retux/3/edit)

Comment: Thanks very much. Would it be possible to set an array (or something like this) to define onlye spedific blocks to be processed? i.e. only "introduction" and "Finish" should be affected..

Comment: Wow. Yes. But I'm missing some p-tags for the unprocessed blocks. In the example above "Something else" and "Another part" should be a p-block...